# Filtering the image and converting to text gives wrong output in python

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

I want to extract a particular text from an image, and I already did some filtering in image but still I'm not getting the exact text.Also is there any way to get a specific text alone from the image?

**Code for filtering the image and converting to text**

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

image = cv2.imread('original.png', 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(thresh, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,   cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)
cv2.imwrite('filtered.png', img)
data = pytesseract.image_to_data(img)
print(data)

cv2.imshow('thresh', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: skip "img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(thresh, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,   cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)". Next, OCR only texts part of the image - IMO it should be easy because in game text should be always at the same position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try **easyOCR** instead of pytesseract

first install by `pip install easyocr`

```
import cv2
import easyocr

image = cv2.imread('original.jpg', 0)
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
result = reader.readtext(image)

#You can use regular expression
interested_string = 'Patrol Rewards'

line = [l[1] for l in result if 'Patrol Rewards' in l[1]]
print(line)
```

You will get list containing interested string like

```
['Patrol Rewards: Courage Horn X 1']
```

This will give correct output but it is bit slow compared to pytesseract on CPU but if you have GPU configured then it is faster. But it gives quite good OCR results.

Comment: Thanks. But I tried installing easyocr on PyCharm and its showing error while installing it

Comment: Can you specify error?

Comment: 40:399: execution error: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torchvision>=0.5 (from easyocr) (from versions: 0.1.6, 0.1.7, 0.1.8, 0.1.9, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.2.post2, 0.2.2.post3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torchvision>=0.5 (from easyocr)
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
 (1)

Comment: you need to upgrade your `pip` library first

Comment: I have tried that code in Google colab. It is working fine.